# TestClass code coverage of search and edit method

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am writing a test class for my controller but don't know how to write a test method for search,edit and cancel methods. If any one can help me i wil appreciate that

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class AgentController3 {
    public List<seit__Agent_Table__c> getAgent {get; set;}
    public seit__Agent_Table__c agent {get; set;}
    public string searchText {get;set;}
    public List<seit__Agent_Table__c> searchResults {get;set;}

    public AgentController3(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        agent=new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        getAgent = [SELECT Id, Name,seit__Agent_Name__c, seit__Email__c, seit__Phone_Number__c,
            seit__Address__c, seit__Bank_Branch__c, seit__Salary__c, seit__Designation__c,
            seit__Company_Name__c, seit__User__c, seit__User_Name__c, CreatedDate
            FROM seit__Agent_Table__c];
    }

    public pageReference SaveAgent()
    {
        try
        {
            upsert agent;  
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetail#');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return pageRef;  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            system.debug(ex);
            PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/a01/o');
            pageRef.setRedirect(true);

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // fired when the search button is clicked
    public PageReference search() 
    {
        String qry='SELECT Id, Name,seit__Agent_Name__c , seit__Email__c, seit__Phone_Number__c, seit__Address__c,seit__Bank_Branch__c,seit__Salary__c,seit__Designation__c,seit__Company_Name__c,seit__User__c,seit__User_Name__c,CreatedDate FROM seit__Agent_Table__c where Name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\' order by Name';
        searchResults = Database.query(qry);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference editAgent() 
    {
        try 
        {
            update searchResults;
        } Catch (DMLException e) 
        {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetail#');
    }

    public PageReference cancel() 
    {
        return new PageReference('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetail#');
    }
}
```

Test class:-

```
@isTest 
private class AgentController3TestClass {
    public string searchText = 'hello';
    static testMethod void SaveA()
    {
        seit__Agent_Table__c a = new seit__Agent_Table__c(seit__Email__c='beenishkhan.2012@gmail.com',seit__Salary__c=20000);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
        AgentController3 controller = new AgentController3(sc);
        controller.SaveAgent();
    }

    static testMethod void saveA1() {

        seit__Agent_Table__c pro = new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(pro);
        AgentController3 controller = new AgentController3(sc);
        controller.SaveAgent();  
    }

    static testMethod void searchTest() {

        seit__Agent_Table__c agent  = new seit__Agent_Table__c();
        agent.Name = "asdfadf";
        insert agent;
        PageReference pageRef = Page.AgentController3TestClass;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('query', 'test');
    }
}
```

Comment: call these method from your test class. I think it will work for you.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma It is working but the code is covering only try blocks not covering the Catch blocks. Can you tell me how to cover the Catch blocks in test classes

Comment: to cover catch block you need to generate some exception. Like try to insert required record without filling required fields.

Comment: As @Tushar mentions, you need to generate exceptions to force the code execution to move into the catch block. The two lines you need to achieve this are:
upsert agent;
and
update searchResults;

Comment: In the test method, input values in the VF page that are illegal and this would throw up an exception. This could either be done by causing system validations(wrong field data types i.e. string in number field) or by causing any custom validations to fire( validation rules or triggers). If none of those are providing an option to cause an exception - you could explicitly throw an exception inside an if block with condition "Test.isRunningTest()" . Thus this code will execute only when the class is invoked by a test class, thus giving it an opportunity to execute the lines in the catch block.

Comment: you should write tests for both positive and negative scenarios. And you should not write test classes only to get coverage, they are called **TEST**-classes and not *coverage*-classes for a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is not code coverage. Your main issue is that your test class has no asserts at all, so it's actually not testing anything.

The idea of a *test* class is to verify that the behaviour of your production code is correct, not to give coverage (coverage without assert is useless).

I would modify your test class to assert the behaviour you want. That is much more important than aiming for higher code coverage. Remember that Salesforce will allow you to deploy your code with 'only' 75% coverage.

I will show an example with one method, which allows you find out how to do the rest:

```
@isTest 
private class AgentController3TestClass {
    public string searchText = 'hello';
    static testMethod void SaveA()
    {
        seit__Agent_Table__c a = new seit__Agent_Table__c(seit__Email__c='beenishkhan.2012@gmail.com',seit__Salary__c=20000);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
        AgentController3 controller = new AgentController3(sc);

        Test.startTest();
        PageReference ref = controller.SaveAgent();
        Test.endTest();

        // Test that the returned pageReference is correct
        System.Assert (ref != null);
        System.AssertEquals ('https://itroos-dev-ed--seit.na34.visual.force.com/apex/AgentDetail#', ref.getUrl());
        System.Assert (true, ref.getRedirect());

        // Test that the agent has been created
        List <seit__Agent_Table__c> agents = [SELECT seit__Email__c, seit__Salary__c
            FROM seit__Agent_Table__c];
        System.AssertEquals (1, agents.size());
        set__Agent_Table__c agent = agents[0];
        System.AssertEquals (2000, agent.seit__Salary__c);
        System.AssertEquals ('beenishkhan.2012@gmail.com', agent.seit__Email__c);
    }
}
```

Perhaps this is not the answer you wanted, but I think this will help you more than trying to achieve 100% code coverage.

If you absolutely want to go for code coverage, then you have to find a way to make the DML fail. If you have some validation rules in the agent, you can try to give the agent some values that will fail validation, throwing an exception. Or you can set the ID field of the agent. On upsert, Salesforce will probably throw an exception and not allow you to upsert a record with a modified ID.